# Camel aggregation strategy xpath example

Tags: java, xml, xpath, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I need an xml to be sent into a queue and be aggregated by one of it's fields using xpath.
That's the code of my RouteBuilder class implementation:

```
public class SimpleRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("activemq:queue:test.input").aggregate(new MyAggregationStrategy()).
                xpath("login/(login)='manager", String.class).completionPredicate(header("aggregated").isEqualTo(5))
                .to("activemq:queue:test.output").end()
        ;
    }
}

class MyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        Message newIn = newExchange.getIn();
        String oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String newBody = newIn.getBody(String.class);
        newIn.setBody(oldBody + newBody);
        return newExchange;
    }
}
```

The xml that is being sent looks like this:

```
<person>
    <login>login</login>
    <password>pass</password>
</person>
```

When I copy this jar into the activemq lib folder and start the activemq, such exception appears:

```
ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid broker URI, no scheme specified: start
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code extract doesn't lead to the reported exception. And I am not sure, what your use case is.

Anyway, following route matches the `login` content of the input messages. When 5 messages with the same login have been received, then the aggregation is sent to the output target. Please note the null check for `oldExchange` in the `aggregate` method:

```
public class SimpleRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("activemq:queue:test.input")
                .aggregate(new MyAggregationStrategy()).xpath("/person/login", String.class)
                .completionSize(5)
                .to("activemq:queue:test.output");
    }
}

public class MyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(final Exchange oldExchange, final Exchange newExchange) {
        Message newIn = newExchange.getIn();
        String newBody = newIn.getBody(String.class);
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            newIn.setBody(newBody);
        } else {
            String oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            newIn.setBody(oldBody + newBody);
        }
        return newExchange;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There's no more exception but it doesn't aggregate messages with the specified login, there are all messages in test.output.